# How to show a terminal under all tabs?

Tags: neovim, terminal, vim8

I have opened few files in tab

```
  vim -p file1 file2 file3
```

When i have opened a tab contains file1, I open a terminal

```
:botright terminal
```

But this terminal is only available for file1 . when I open other tabs file2 and file 3 , the terminal is not shown under. Is there a way to show a terminal under all tabs? (like vscode where terminal is static and we can move between tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no, it is not possible.

If you look at `:help windows-intro`, the following (among other) is said:

```
   A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.                                                                                                                                                                       
   A window is a viewport on a buffer.                                                                                                                                                                             
   A tab page is a collection of windows.
```

There is some hierarchy here between the windows and tabs.

So, to take your view, which (I think) looks like that:

[image]

The terminal is in a window and it belongs to the first tab (where foo is currently open).

So having the terminal being independent of the tabs would mean to have a window independent of the tabs, which goes against the above hierarchy.

Comment: Of course, you can open a terminal in each tab, but these would be different terminals, not a single one.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you open each file in a different tab with `-p`?  The standard way to open multiple files is to open them in different buffers.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710166) for more about buffers vs windows vs tabs.

You can cycle through the buffer displayed in the top window with `:bnext` and similar.  The workflow I would suggest to achieve what you want would be something like:

1. Open the files you want with `vim file1 file2 file3`
2. Open a new terminal below with `:terminal`
3. After doing what you want in the terminal, switch to the top window with Ctrl-W k
4. Make some edits, cycle to the next file with `:bnext` etc whilst keeping the terminal visible below.

Comment: I can visually see what are all the files are opened if opened in tab. Also i can use {n}gt to go to tab easier. it is more intuitive than buffer for me.

Comment: Tab pages are not designed for what you describe (the name "tab pages" can often be a source of confusion; they are best regarded as "preset views").  There are many plugins that can show a list of buffers if you find that useful e.g. [vim-bufferline](https://github.com/bling/vim-bufferline) and [lightline-bufferline](https://github.com/mengelbrecht/lightline-bufferline)